# Output registered users as Json in spring mvc

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a simple form for registration with generated id and then title, username and password. Once user is registered I want to go to Json page and be able to pull that data in there, is that even possible? if so how is it done? This is what I have at the moment but that doesn't work.

Model:

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=6)
    private String password;

    public String getTitle() { return title; }

    public String getUsername() { return username; }

    public String getPassword() { return password; }

    public Long getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }

    public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }

    public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }

    public List<Note> getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    @OneToMany
    private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
}
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public User json(){
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(id);
        user.setTitle(title);
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password);
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a normal Spring MVC or a REST service?

Comment: I don't know what REST service means so I guess I have normal Spring

Comment: Response from `/json` api to the client(browser) will be a json string like `{ "id" : 1, "title" : "SO", "username" : "przemek", "password" : "wojtas"}`, rather than a webpage. Is that you want from that api?  Also, please clarify **I want to go to Json page and be able to pull that data in there**.